# BizTalk 2016 WCF-WebHttp Caching Headers

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2016

I've created a send pipeline with only a custom pipeline component which creates a mime message to POST to a Rest API that requires a multipart/form-data. It works but fails for every 2nd invocation. It alternates between success and failure. When it fails, the boundary I've written to the header appears to be overwritten by the WCF-WebHttp adapter using the boundary of the previously successful message.

- I've made sure that I'm writing the correct boundary to the header.
- Any streams I've used in the pipeline component have been added to the pipeline resource manager.
- If I restart the host instance after the first successful message, the next message will be successful.
- Waiting 10 minutes between processing each message has no change in the observed behaviour.
- If I send a different file through when the failure is expected to occur, the header content-length is still the same as the previous file. This suggests that the header used is exactly the same as the previous invocation.
- The standard BizTalk mime component doesn't write the boundary to the header, so doesn't offer any clue.

Success

```
POST http://somehost/Record HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary="9ccdeb0a-c407-490c-9cce-c5e3be639785"
Host: somehost
Content-Length: 11989
Expect: 100-continue
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate

--9ccdeb0a-c407-490c-9cce-c5e3be639785
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=uri

6442
--9ccdeb0a-c407-490c-9cce-c5e3be639785
```

Fail: boundary in header not same as in payload

```
POST http://somehost/Record HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary="9ccdeb0a-c407-490c-9cce-c5e3be639785"
Host: somehost
Content-Length: 11989
Expect: 100-continue
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate

--3fe3e969-8a41-451c-aae7-8458aee0c9f4
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=uri

6442
--3fe3e969-8a41-451c-aae7-8458aee0c9f4
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=Files; filename=testdoc.docx; filename*=utf-8''testdoc.docx
```

My problem will be fixed if I can get the header to use the correct boundary. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm more surprised you actually had some success with this approach. The thing is, the headers aren't officially message properties but are port properties. And ports cache their settings. You have to make it a dynamic send port for it to properly work. Another way is by setting the headers in a custom behavior, but I don't think that suits your scenario.